# JSF Ajax returns empty 304 response - causing page to crash

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I have this error message in a browser and page stops responding:

```
core.js.xhtml?ln=primefaces&v=6.0:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of undefined
```

It seems that this Tomcat or JSF is caching POST requests!

[image]

I tried to [move css on the bottom on the page](http://maxyermayank.blogspot.com.tr/2013/10/jsf-ajax-response-returning-empty.html?showComment=1454339705279) - it doesn't help.

Comment: Which Code is throwing this issue ? Look Like Some Primefaces component using HTML5 features .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was to put special phase listener to force browser to invalidate  cache:

**faces-config.xml**

```
<lifecycle>
    <phase-listener id="nocache">com.xxxx.jsf.util.CacheControlPhaseListener</phase-listener>
    <phase-listener>org.primefaces.component.lifecycle.LifecyclePhaseListener</phase-listener>
    <phase-listener>com.xxxx.jsf.listeners.BackButtonPhaseListener</phase-listener>
</lifecycle>
```

**class:**

```
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseEvent;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseId;
import javax.faces.event.PhaseListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class CacheControlPhaseListener implements PhaseListener {
    public PhaseId getPhaseId() {
        return PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE;
    }

    public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    }

        public void beforePhase(PhaseEvent event) {
            FacesContext facesContext = event.getFacesContext();
            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
            response.addHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            // Stronger according to blog comment below that references HTTP spec
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
            response.addHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate");
            // some date in the past
            response.addHeader("Expires", "Mon, 8 Aug 2006 10:00:00 GMT");
        }
    }
```